# 'gunzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. System command 'gunzip' failed

Tags: gzip, gunzip

I am trying to analyse my raw GNSS data on the GNSS Analyser app from here https://github.com/google/gps-measurement-tools. The installation guide includes the following step:

4.2 gunzip installation
The automatic ftp code inside GnssAnalysis will download ephemeris zip files, and attempt to
`unzip` them using `gunzip`.

- Download `gzip.exe` from here http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gzip/gzip-1.9.zip
- Extract the files from the `zip` file, rename `gzip.exe` to `gunzip.exe`
- Move `gunzip.exe` to somewhere in your Windows path (type `path` in the Windows
  Command Prompt to see what your path is, typically you will find a directory
  `C:\Windows\system32` and you can put `gunzip.exe` there.)

However, upon downloading `gunzip`, I cant find a `gzip.exe` file, and hence tried renaming the `gzip.c` and `gzip.h` file instead. It did not work and I got this error when attempting to process my own raw data.

Comment: `gzip -d` should do the trick. `man gzip` should provide you with more features you might need for your particular task.

Comment: Hi, would you be able to elaborate? I dont see any gzip -d file amongst the unzipped gunzip folder. Thank you and sorry if the question seems stupid, I am a beginner who needs this for my school project!

Comment: `-d` is an option you pass to the command to tell it to `decompress`. There are many more options that are explained by calling `man gzip`

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried and got success to import DB from a backup file:

```
gzip -d < C:\Users\my-user\Downloads\my-db-backup.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p MY_DB_NAME
```